# Spring boot component is facing nullpointer when running in unit test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

My Spring Boot app has a `Controller` that uses a `Service` that uses a bean I created (`SharkMaster`) that uses some values from a `properties` file.

When I'm running the app in regular mode it works OK.

However, when trying to run a unit test for the controller class, and providing it with a mock `service` it tries to create the real SharkMaster bean and fails since it can't find the values from the configuration.

I saw [several posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353327/populating-spring-value-during-unit-test)  and read some [blog posts](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-separate-data-source) about similar issues, but at the current stage, the app is crashing in `NullPointer` when trying to run in unit test mode.

```
@Configuration
public class SharkMaster{

@Value("${sharkName}")
private String sharkName;

public SharkMaster(){
  // sharkName is null here and the NullPointer is thrown
}
```

The Controller test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(SharkController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SharkMaster.class})
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.yml")
public class SharkControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private SharkService sharkService;
```

I tried to add `@PropertySource("classpath:application-test.yml")` to the Controller test class but it didn't help.

I believe this question is not the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50525053/property-values-in-bean-class-are-null-in-constructor) , because the situation here in during the unit tests phase.

Comment: plz refer this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48329375/spring-boot-integration-test-business-layer/48335181#48335181)

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `@ContextConfiguration` and Try like this.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = SharkController.class)
public class SharkControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@InjectMocks
private SharkService sharkService;

@Mock
private SharkMaster sharkMaster;

.......
}
```

Comment: When doing this, the error is different: No qualifying bean of type 'SharkMaster' available

Comment: another way to do is, create a mock of SharkMaster and do @InjectMocks for SharkService

Comment: #pvpkiran that did the trick. Thanks!